# Conflict between Matplotlib animation and Matplotlib widget?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I created this very simple animation of a circle with Matplotlib:

```
from numpy import sin, cos, pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

class MyCircle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.diameter =  0.5

    def set_diameter(self,val):
        self.diameter = val

    def get_shape(self,time):
        return plt.Circle((cos(time),sin(time)), self.diameter+0.3*sin(time))

circle = MyCircle()

# Figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(-2, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

# Slider
ax_diam = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg='lightgoldenrodyellow')
sl_diam = Slider(ax_diam, 'Diameter', 0.1, 2, valinit=circle.diameter)
sl_diam.on_changed(lambda val: circle.set_diameter(val))

# Animation
def animate(i): 
    shape = circle.get_shape(i*2*pi/100)
    ax.clear()
    ax.add_patch(shape)
    return [shape]

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=25, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: animation]

I added a slider to dynamically update the diameter of the circle during the animation. Now, this works but has various noticeable flaws:

- When I drag the mouse on the Slider, the animation is slowed down... This is not so bad in this example, but my (real) use-case requires heavier work in the background.
- The initial circle always appears on the plot (on the right). I'd like to remove it, but somehow `ax.clear()` doesn't do the trick.
- When I resize the window, the background turns black as on the following picture:

[image: animation black]

I am new to Matplotlib, so it's very likely that I am doing this wrong. Any idea?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, but in a nutshell, you'll need to remove `blit=True` from the `FuncAnimation`.  You can use blitting with this, but you'll need to handle it manually.

Comment: Thanks @JoeKington, I think it pretty much resolves all three problems. (Not sure that the animation isn't slowed down at all, but it feels smoother)